# Server Error in '/' Application ASP>NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC 5 project, I had a default Account Controller which I removed, and then replaced it with the user controller. When i try to open the user controller with address: `http://localhost:49669/users/create ,` 
it links me directly to `http://localhost:49669/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fusers%2fcreate .`
 and i get the Server Error in '/' application because i have removed the Account controller.

Is anything wrong with my routing?

web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at your web.config to see the authentication settings.

Comment: Ok, so now do you see where the problem is?

Comment: what changes should i make?

Comment: I dont understand why i keepings on loading that page when i enter other URL.

Comment: Well, you're being redirected to that page that no longer exists because of those lines in your web.config and presumably an [Authenticated] attribute on you new controller / action.